# Proof that the product of a symmetric matrix and its transpose is also symmetric

Tags: matrix-calculus

If A is a symmetric matrix, then verify that A×A' (transpose) and also A'×A is also symmetric

Comment: I'm looking for where to start

Comment: Already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387243/given-a-square-matrix-a-both-aat-and-ata-are-symmetric/387249)

Comment: Begin by proving : $$(1)\;\;(A^t)^t=A\;,\;\;\;(2)\;\;(AB)^t=B^tA^t$$ The above is all you need now.

Comment: The claim holds for *every* $m\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in general $$(AB)'=B'A'$$

For a symmetric matrix we have $A'=A$

$$AA'=A'A=A^2$$
$$(AA')'=A''A=A^2=AA'$$
$$(A'A)'=A'A''=A^2=A'A$$